# Is it safe to call banks from Skype?

Tags: encryption, voip

Say, you call Wells Fargo's or Fidelity's customer support number, from Skype. Example number: 1-800-869-3557

You use Skype because you're overseas and because Skype lets you call US numbers for free. You do not have a paid Skype account. It's a regular free account.

On the call, you type things like account number and PIN. You say things like your phone number, address on file and other sensitive information.

Is there an end to end encryption from my end to the bank's like HTTPS connection?

Answer (score 3):

Skype calls are not end to end encrypted, because phone calls are not encrypted. It's not even close to HTTPS encryption, but it's as safe as your regular phone line.

If you are comfortable calling your bank from your landline or your cell phone, you can be comfortable with Skype too.

Some will point that Skype has the opportunity to listen to your calls, but so does your telecom provider. And your calls are protected by laws and regulations, and both Skype and your telecom will not risk the reputation damage nor the regulatory fines bu snooping on your calls.